# access value of an array through the name in the Expression in Power Automate/ MS flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I have created an empty list and appending to it in the flow, at the end, I need to get the value of a specific key through an **Expression**, Is this possible? and if yes, how?

Please see the below screenshots.

**Initialise:**

[image]

**Append:**

[image]

I am appending data to this array in a Do while loop, the content of each run (total 2 run) is shown below:

First Run:

[image]

Second Run:

[image]

And the output of Compose"

```
[
  {
    "name": "Fy2020",
    "value": 2.5
  },
  {
    "name": "Fy2021",
    "value": 2.5
  } 
]
```

**Retrieve and assign it to another variable:**

[image]

I have tried different approaches and got different errors:

variables('FYearsValues')?['value']?[0] erorr:

```
 'The template language expression 'variables('FYearsValues')?['value']?[0]' cannot be evaluated 
     because property 'value' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an 
   integer index. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.
```

variables('FYearsValues')?['Value']?[0]
Error:

```
The template language expression 'variables('FYearsValues')?['Value']?[0]' cannot be
  evaluated because property 'Value' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an
  integer index. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.
```

variables('FYearsValues')[0]
Error:

```
The variable 'FYCounter_' of type 'Integer' cannot be initialized or updated with value '{
 "name": "Fy2020",
 "value": 2.5
 }' of type 'Object'. The variable 'FYCounter_' only supports values of types 'Integer'.
```

and for this:
variables('FYearsValues')['Fy2020']
Error:

```
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Set_variable_3' inputs at line '1' and 
column '2857': 'The template language expression 'variables('FYearsValues')['Fy2020']' cannot be 
 evaluated because property 'Fy2020' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an 
integer index. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.
```

**The best formula for me would be something like this**

variables('FYearsValues')['Fy2020']  which needs to return 2.5 (i.e.value)

but I can work with indexes too (e.g. variables('FYearsValues')[0]  which needs to return 2.5 (i.e.value)

Comment: I can also work with any similar object like a data dictionary or something else, I mainly need to be able to access the value by calling the key, maybe a string that I can split with  ',' and then do another split based on ':' and this must be done through **Expression**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an array, you would access it with index starting at 0 like

```
 variables('MyArray')?[1]
```

Index can be a variable as well, in that case it would be like

```
variables('MyArray')?[variables('varIndex')]
```

[image]

However, if it's a JSON object collection, then first need to find the item by the index and then find the items' value by property name. In the example below, [results] is a collection of items, but retrieving user email by property

```
body('Parse_JSON')?['d']?['results'][1]['User']['Email']
```

Comment: Thanks there, Can you please explain the JSON part more, what is json format and what are User and Email that you are referring to? Regarding "then first need to find the item by the index" How can I find the correct index?

Comment: Added more screenshots to show the content of my JSON array? Do I need to Compose?

Comment: Upvoted (and Thx again) as after composing and using outputs('Compose')?[0]?['name'] and outputs('Compose')?[0]?['value'] I was able to get the name and value of array but still need to find the value based on a given name in the Expression, (i.e. not through the apply each) . However, I am able to find the correct index by using some variables dynamically but still keen to see if there is a quick way to search an array based on name in an Expression

Comment: To check if a value exists in an Array, a collection of JSON objects or a string variable, use contains() function like: contains(variables('MainArray'), 'Matt'). It returns true or false. Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Thx @Matiur, I am running contains(outputs('Compose'), 'Fy2020') as an expression and it always returns false while this item as 'name' exists in my JSON array, do you know how could I change the query to return true?

Comment: You might need to convert to string() first before comparing like from my example: contains(string(outputs('Compose_2')), '20')

Comment: Woked thanks a lot

Comment: was able to find the index through keeping a pointer, so the final code of mine which identify the index is as below, may help others, although the first part can be optimised by using contain, if(and(greaterOrEquals(2020, variables('PrjFYStart_Year')),lessOrEquals(2020,variables('PrjFYEnd_Year'))),outputs('Compose')?[if(greaterOrEquals(sub(variables('PrjFYStart_Year'),2020),0),sub(variables('PrjFYStart_Year'),2020),sub(2020,variables('PrjFYStart_Year')))]?['value'] ,0)

Comment: Please upvote if you find my question valuable to others

Answer (score 2):

> I have created an empty list and appending to it in the flow, at the end, I need to get the value of a specific key through an Expression, Is this possible? and if yes, how?

**Initialize Variables:**

*Your example array*

[image: example array]

*Integer counter (used in do until loop)*

[image: temporary string variable]

*Temporary String tempString (used to get value from array)*

[image: current string value from array]

**Loop through Array:**

[image: high-level array loop]

*Do Until Loop Details*

[image: do until loop condition details]

*Switch Loop Details*

[image: switch loop condition details]

```
variables('FYearsValues')[variables('counter')].name
```

*Switch Loop Condition Case Details*

[image: switch loop condition case details]

```
variables('FYearsValues')[variables('counter')].value
```

*Increment Variable Details*

[image: increment counter in do until loop condition]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although the problem was solved a long time ago, upvoted.